# Running a open source php project after modifications

Tags: php, apache

I was looking for an open source php website code and found one at http://projects.students3k.com/online-exam-website-php-source-code.html and downloaded it. It doesnt have a read me so I suppose it involves something which is common sense to people who use php.

Subsequently, I installed apache2, placed the whole stuff in var/www/ and connected to the database.

1. What I'm unable to do is find any users to login to the user or admin interface. I did find a file with some users in a csv format but it doesn't work
2. The instructions say I have to make changes to a file lib/db.php for adding my local parameters.

This is not any sort of homework and I really wanna explore the functionality of this website.

P.S. - The file size is 80 Mb before i'm scolded for posting such links.

P.P.S - It will reallllly help me and I have smashed my head trying.

db.php file after modifications :

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWD', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('ADMIN_URL', 'localhost/admin/');
define('URL', 'localhost/');
define('IMAGEURL', '/var/www/images');

define('Site_Admin_Name','http://online-test.students3k.com/admin/');
define('Site_Name', 'http://online-test.students3k.com/');
define('Admin_folder_Name', '/var/www/admin/web');
define('Admin_Path','<a href="../home.php" style="text-decoration: none;">Admin</a>
                         <span class="org_arrow"><b>&raquo;</b></span>');
define('Site_Title', 'Ismart Exams');
define('Admin_Site_Title', 'Ismart Exams :: Admin Panel');
```

Comment: what did you do with the instructions to change `lib/db.php`?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? The login is rejected or there is a PHP error?

Comment: I don't want to sound doubtful, but a PHP project that assumes WAMP to work makes me suspicious about its overall quality.

Comment: @Romainberger- I dont have a user and password combination to login. My best guess is this has resulted in no tables getting created in mysql though I'm not sure if I am correct.

Comment: @SirDarius - I really wanna see the flow and working of the website so even if it is not one of the best practices, anything that can make it 'demo'able would suffice for me to understand a lot! :)

Comment: This is not homework, but only an "online test project for students". Yay. Why not use any other project ? Try installing a wordpress, you could get a lot more informations and it's very popular and well documented

Comment: @Lepidosteus - Yes this is listed as a project on some website and you have your reasons to be suspicious but it's quite comprehensive I believe so want to give it a shot! :)

Comment: @R1234 if you really want to explore this project and test it. Don't. If there is a html anchor tag defined in the config instead of just the path itself, then I say: abort mission and find something which is set up correctly. Because this is really weird. I have never seen a complete finished anchor tag including markup in a global constant. Weird.

Comment: @Jelmer - That is what I had planned to do but came here thinking may be there's something obvious that this developer did not leave a single trace of readme or instructions. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the data into your database. The file is located at

```
database/ismartexams.sql
```

After you imported the data there will be three users available.

1. admin
2. testengine
3. superadmin

Their passwords are equal to the username.